# Plotting issue with Matplotlib, graph starts from 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I tried to plot an array with int numbers,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
plt.plot(Raw,color='Steelblue')
plt.ylabel('Signal Power',size=20)
plt.xlabel('Base Number',size=20)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
```

Result do not show the bottom of the columns (zero to one region)

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: I suspect that your data, `raw`, does not go lower than y=1.

Comment: Right @swatchai 
Thanks to Lara-ipek suggestion, after replacing the nan values with zero it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `plt.ylim(ymin=0)` to this:

```
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
```

The command was updated in Matplotlib 3.3. Here is the [command](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) from the docs.

Comment: I have it in the code, it is not the solution

Comment: @Shrm In your code, do you have it before or after you create the plot?